# Error Importing XChange into Eclipse via Maven2Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, eclipse-plugin, shared-libraries

I followed these instructions: [Getting Started with XChange for Noobies](https://github.com/timmolter/XChange/wiki/Getting-Started-with-XChange-for-Noobies)
 to install [XChange](https://github.com/timmolter/XChange), a Java library to trade on Bitcoin XChanges. I cloned the GitHub repo onto my computer and I used the Maven2Eclipse plugin to import the repo. But I got a bunch of red x's on the files in the package explorer.

[Eclipse Package Explorer Errors Img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uoWjH.png)

When I run the example from "Getting Started," BitstampTickerDemo.java, I get a warning that errors exist in the other projects I imported, and when I proceed, I get a compiler error: 
`ExchangeFactory cannot be resolved`
Probably because the library was not successfully imported.

I've tried various things, including renaming the cloned repo "xchange-parent", but nothing seems to work. Help! I need to make my millions trading Bitcoin! What could I be doing wrong?

Comment: Can you compile using "mvn clean install" from the command line?

Comment: @Thorbjørn I navigated to the xchange-parent directory in Terminal and ran "mvn clean install," received a `BUILD SUCCESS`, and then refreshed xchange-parent, but the result was the same: red x's and the same errors when I run an example class.

Comment: So the maven build is fine.  Then the problem is most likely inside Eclipse.  My guess would be that the build contains plugins not properly emulated by m2e.  I would suggest using IntelliJ (community edition) or Netbeans IDE's for this project instead of Eclipse as Maven support is better.

Comment: @Thorbjørn I imported the project into IntelliJ and it worked. Thanks for your help! It's odd that the repo's getting started guide is outdated.

Comment: You’re welcome. Consider raising an issue with the project that their documentation is outdated.